# trying to set Paint() color to primary theme

Tags: flutter, dart

trying to set the color to the primary theme in my flutter app, get an error where context is saying The argument type 'PaintingContext' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'. any idea how to fix this?

```
   final paint = Paint()

  ..color = Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary; //Thumb Background Color
  ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
```

Comment: Are you trying to draw with a CustomPainter?

Comment: yes, its for a customer slider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What might be happening is that you are trying to use a `PaintingContext` where you should use an object of type `BuildContext`.
To solve this you could either pass the `BuildContext` or directly the color to the `CustomPainter`.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add a color property

```
class MyCustomPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final Color color;
  MyCustomPainter(this.color);

}
```

and then use it like

```
Container(
color: Colors.transparent,
width: double.infinity,
height: 70,
child: CustomPaint(
painter: MyCustomPainter(Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor),),)
```